# Upload directory with sub-directories in java and azure blob storage sdk

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I use this code for upload files to azure blob storage, but when i try load directory with sub-directories i get error "FileNotFoundException encountered: C:\upload\bin" :(Access is denied), is any solution to load files and directories in source directory?

```
try {
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

        // Container name must be lower case.
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
        container.createIfNotExists();
        File source = new File(path);
        if (source.list().length > 0) {
            for (File file : source.listFiles()) {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(file.getName());
                if (blob.exists() == false) {
                    File sourceFile = new File(source + "\\" + file.getName());
                    blob.upload(new FileInputStream(sourceFile), sourceFile.length());
                    System.out.println("File " + source + "\\" + file.getName() + " Load to blob storage");
                } else System.out.println("File " + source + "\\" + file.getName() + " Already exist in storage");
            }
        } else System.out.println("In folder " + path + " are no files ");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        System.out.print("FileNotFoundException encountered: ");
        System.out.println(fileNotFoundException.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);

    } catch (StorageException storageException) {
        System.out.print("StorageException encountered: ");
        System.out.println(storageException.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Exception encountered: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: I guess `source + "\\" + file.getName()` doesn't contain the sub-directory of the listed file? Isn't `file` enough, why do you need to construct another variable `sourceFile`?

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft  thank for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft said, the `file` object generated by `source.listFiles()` is enough for gettting the absolute file path via `file.getAbsolutePath()`, so you can write your code as below.

```
if (blob.exists() == false) {
    blob.uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
} else System.out.println("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " Already exist in storage");
```

I test your code in my environment, it also works. However, per my experience, your issue `FileNotFoundException encountered: C:\upload\bin" :(Access is denied)` was caused by lacking the permission of accessing files under `C:` or `C:\upload\bin`. So you need to run your code as administrator on your current Windows environment, as the figures below.

Fig 1. Run your code as administrator if using IntelliJ

[image]

Fig 2. Run your code as administrator if using Eclipse

[image]

Fig 3. Run your code as administrator via Command Prompt

[image]

---

**Update**:
On Azure Blob Storage, the file and directory structure is depended on the blob name. So if you want to see the file structure like the figures below, you can use the code `String blobName = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(path, "");` to get the blob name.

Fig 4. The file and directory structure built on my local machine
[image]

Fig 5. The same above on Azure Blob Storage via Azure Storage Explorer
[image]

Here is my complete code.

```
private static final String path = "D:\\upload\\";
private static final String storageConnectionString = "<your storage connection string>";
private static final String containerName = "<your container for uploading>";

private static CloudBlobClient serviceClient;

public static void upload(File file) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException, StorageException, IOException {
    // Container name must be lower case.
    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference(containerName);
    container.createIfNotExists();
    String blobName = file.getAbsolutePath().replace(path, "");
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    if (blob.exists() == false) {
        blob.uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        System.out.println("File " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " Already exist in storage");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
    serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();
    File source = new File(path);
    for (File fileOrDir : source.listFiles()) {
        boolean isFile = fileOrDir.isFile();
        if(isFile) {
            upload(fileOrDir);
        } else {
            for(File file: fileOrDir.listFiles()) {
                upload(file);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: my first code perfectly works with upload files with any errors, i get error when i put in directory a sub directory, i change my code as @Peter Pan told, like this:

`if (blob.exists() == false) {
                        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        blob.uploadFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    } 
else System.out.println("File " + file.getAbsolutePath()+ " Already exist in storage");`
but it upload only files

Comment: @Юрий Did you want to upload blob named like `upload/bin/<filename>` or `<sub-dirctory name under C:\upload\bin>/<filename>`?

Comment: in directory C:\upload i have sub-directories bin, backup, archive, with some files, i want to upload this structure to blob storage

Comment: i want get a structure in blob like this: 
 bin/
  - file1
  - file2
  - fileN
backup/
  - file1
  - file2
  - fileN
`

Comment: @Юрий I updated my post. Hope it helps for your needs.

Comment: thank you very much, it perfectly works, my respect!